How to add entire graphql schema to another schema using Pothos GraphQL?
I have two GraphQL schema. I need to add all the types (including Query and Mutation type) from one schema to another schema, ultimately resulting in a single GraphQL schema for end users. To achieve this, I am using @pothos/plugin-add-graphql plugin.
This plugins works very well and copies Objects, Interfaces, Enums, Unions but it doesn't copy Query and Mutation fields defined on first schema.
Both schemas are defined using Pothos.
Is there any way to achieve this via some other means?
